# GPUImage stillCamera crash iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

Hi I'm currently working on a camera using GPUImage, and I've got a strange bug only happening on iPhone 4s : whenever I try to capture an image using capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter: it crashes the app without any error.
Using sleep or animateWithDuration before and after the call made it works 1 out of 5 try more or less.

Using GPUImage filter functions like useNextFrameForImageCapture and imageFromCurrentFrameBuffer the app doesn't crash anymore, but I don't get the image every time.

It's been a few days and I'm quite stuck so any answer will be welcome.

EDIT :

To be more precise I'm testing my code on iPhone 4, 4s and 5.
On 4 and 5, no problem with this code :

```
- (void) takePicture
{

if (self.occupied)
    return;
self.occupied = true;
self.focus.isFocusing = true;
[self setPreviewOrientation];
[[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] purgeAllUnassignedFramebuffers];
@autoreleasepool {
    [stillCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:filter.currentFilter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedImage, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:processedImage];
    [self.delegate finishedCapturingImage:img];
    self.occupied = false;
    }];
}
}
```

But on 4s the application crash and I managed to narrow it to this specific block of code in GPUImageStillCamera.m  :

```
AVCaptureDevicePosition currentCameraPosition = [[videoInput device] position];
        if ( (currentCameraPosition != AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) || (![GPUImageContext supportsFastTextureUpload]) || !requiresFrontCameraTextureCacheCorruptionWorkaround)
        {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(frameRenderingSemaphore);
            [finalFilterInChain useNextFrameForImageCapture];
            [self captureOutput:photoOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:imageSampleBuffer fromConnection:[[photoOutput connections] objectAtIndex:0]];
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        }
```

As I said using imageFromCurrentFrameBuffer doesn't crash the app and get the image every time on 4s (but not on 4 and 5) but it's not a full resolution image which is what I'm trying to obtain.

Crash log show that I'm using almost all of the memory of the device.
If anyone have the slightest clue to optimize the memory usage of GPUImage or any work around it would be greatly appreciated.

(I apologize if I'm not clear enough English isn't my native language)

Comment: What crash do you get ? Please post a crash log.

Comment: No crash log to give as I stated there is no error when debugging with Xcode I receive a disconnect message.